# Multiple Solutions? Suppose ${x^2}+{y^2} = 45$ and $x=2y$ ... find $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, related-rates

Suppose ${x^2}+{y^2} = 45$ and $x=2y$ for positive values of $x$ and $y$ find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ when $\frac{dx}{dt}=2$

I am new to implicit differntiation and related rates. When I attempted to solve this problem, I was met with multiple solutions. It is my first time working with two seperate equations and was wondering why two solutions is possible and what they would mean in context. Thank you.

Solution 1:

$$\frac{d}{dt}[x=2y]$$
$$\implies\frac{dx}{dt}=2\frac{dy}{dt}$$
$$\implies2=2\frac{dy}{dt}$$
$$\implies\frac{dy}{dt}=1$$

Solution 2:
$$\frac{d}{dt}[{x^2}+{y^2} = 45]$$
$$\implies2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$\implies2(2y)(2)+2y\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$\implies4+\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$\implies\frac{dy}{dt}=-4$$
Solution 3: (admittedly the same as sol. 2)
$${x^2}+{y^2} = 45 \quad \Bbb{and} \quad x=2y$$
$$\implies{(2y)^2}+{y^2} = 45$$
$$\implies {5y^2} = 45$$
$$\implies {y} = 3 \Bbb {\quad [ignore\, \pm\, because\, of\, original\, question]}$$
$$\Bbb{and}\quad{x=6}$$
$$\Bbb{we\,recall} \quad 2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$\implies 2(6)(2)+2(3)\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{24}{6}=-4$$

Comment: Solutions 2 and 3 are correct , since both given conditions have to be met simultaneously (as well as $ \ (x \ , \ y) \ $ being in the first quadrant), so the object is at $ \ x \ = \ 6 \ \ , \ \ y \ = \ 3 \ \ . $  Solution 1 ignores the requirement that the object be on the given circle.  By the way, the second-to-last step in Solution 2 is risky:  you got away with it because $ \ y \ \neq \ 0 \ $ for the given situation, so you were not dividing an equatio through by zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a typical implicit differentiation problem. If that was the case, we would be discussing if the equations can define $x$ as a function of $y$ or vice-versa. In this case, the equations and the positivity condition dictate that $x=3$ and $y=6$. So, if you want to imagine that $x,y$ are functions of a new variable $t$, you can only conclude that they are constant functions and that the derivatives with respect to $t$ are both zero.

Comment: Let's say indeed that OP's question is badly worded. OP's calculations make sense nonetheless. That's what I tried to do in my answer. This could then help him to better understand why his question is badly formulated, to better understand his calculations and finally to better formulate his question in such a way as to avoid an answer of the type of yours. But I recognize that your answer in the state of the question of the post is the correct one. I should have asked OP to clarify his question before giving my answer.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Different answers are just fine. They can all be useful to the OP and they are posted with that intention. I have no doubt that your answer fits very well the intended question, just not the actual question :)

Answer (score 0):

The context is elementary; it is a context where one can perfectly understand the situation before approaching less traditional situations; in other words, we can practice there like you did.
It's elementary geometry: tangents at the intersection points of a circle and a straight line; the tangents are perpendicular to the radii at the two intersection points $\color{blue}{B=(6,3)}$ and $B'=(-6,-3 )$. You ignore $B'$.
The idea is to parameterize the circle with a *functional* relation (implicit *function*), here $\color{green}{\begin{cases} x=2t \\ y=\varphi(t)\end{cases}}$, at least locally (hence the small rectangle drawn around $\color{blue}B$ in the illustration.)

Hence the $\frac{dx}{dt}=2$, which first allows you by parameterizing the line to obtain $4t^2+t^2=45\iff t=\mp3$ and the points $\color{blue}B$ and $B'$.
Note that for the line the parameterization is $\begin{cases} x=2t \\ y=t\end{cases}$, but this is obviously no longer the case for the circle parameterization and that is why I introduced a function $\color{green}{\varphi}$.

You finally get in your "solution 2" $\frac{dy}{dt}=-4$, hence $\color{green}{\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt}=2 \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=\varphi^{'}(3)=-4\end{cases}}$

Which gives you a direction vector of the tangent $T$ at $\color{blue}B$, $\color{red}{u=(2,-4)}$.
[image]